# How to define multiple <security:form-login> in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using **Spring Security** to realize system login function. There are multiple login page in system, if there are any errors when logining, the page will redirect to **xxx?error=true**. And I have configured one `<security:form-login>` successfully in xml file as below:

```
<!-- Default security config -->
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:anonymous username="anonymous" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"  />

    <!-- session stealing is prevented by using secure GUID cookie -->
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" requires-channel="https"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" requires-channel="https" />

    <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            always-use-default-target="false" 
            default-target-url="/"  />

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.http.port')}"
            https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.ssl.port')}" />
        <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />

    </security:port-mappings>

    <security:request-cache ref="httpSessionRequestCache" />

</security:http>

<bean id="loginAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?error=true"/>
</bean>
```

But there is another login page named **facebook-login**, how to defined another `<security:form-login/>` to realize that if there are errors in **/facebook-login**, the page will redirect to **/facebook-login?error=true**?
(I only want to achieve it through configuring xml file base on my xml snippet, but not through annotation)

Answer (score 0):

You should append a new `<security:http>` tag in xml, and use `pattern="/facebook-login/**"` to filter your login page. In tag `<security:form-login>` **login-processing-url** cannot also be **"/j_spring_security_check"**, you can use **"/facebook-login/j_spring_security_check"**. eg:

```
<!-- Security config for Facebook login - it has its own login page -->
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" pattern="/facebook-login/**">
    <security:anonymous username="anonymous" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"  />

    <!-- session stealing is prevented by using secure GUID cookie -->
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    <!-- SSL / AUTHENTICATED pages -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/facebook-login*" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/facebook-login/**" requires-channel="https" />

    <security:form-login
            login-page="/facebook-login"
            login-processing-url="/facebook-login/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFacebookAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="loginGuidAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            always-use-default-target="false"
            default-target-url="/" />

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.http.port')}"
            https="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('tomcat.ssl.port')}" />
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
    </security:port-mappings>

    <security:request-cache ref="httpSessionRequestCache" />

</security:http>

<bean id="loginFacebookAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/facebook-link?error=true"/>
</bean>
```